# How to merge data in arrays with Set::combine in cakephp2?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to merge the data in the arrays 'c' and 'a' inside `MyData` with the following code, but recently found out that there is a function called Set::combine. How can I use the combine method in CakePHP 2? I searched for tutorials but can't find a decent one that can actually help me out with the solution. Some examples or tips will be great!

I want to merge `[my_test]` and `[my_date]` inside `[MyData]` with Set::combine.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MyData] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 79
                    [my_birth_day] => 1990-06-20
                    [my_address] => 400
                    [my_age] => 26
                    [my_name] => Joy
                    [my_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2017-06-19 15:39:44
                )

            [c] => Array
                (
                    [my_test] => math
                )

            [a] => Array
                (
                    [my_date] => 2017-08-13
                )

        ).....Loops

    [1] => Array
        (
```

I would want the result to be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
    [MyData] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 79
                    [my_birth_day] => 1990-06-20
                    [my_address] => 400
                    [my_age] => 26
                    [my_name] => Joy
                    [my_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2017-06-19 15:39:44
                    [my_test] => math
                    [my_date] => 2017-08-13
```

I wrote this code to merge the arrays and display it as the above code, but I want to use Set::combine the $res.

```
$res = $this->find( 'all', $cond); // All the data are fetchd from this $res
            $count = count($res);
            for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
               $result[] =  $res[$i] ;

                $fixed_arrays[] = $result[$i]['MyData'];
                if (!empty($result[$i]['c'])) {
                    $corrupt_c_array = $result[$i]['c'];
                    $fixed_arrays = array_merge($fixed_arrays,$corrupt_c_array);
                }
                if(!empty($result[$i]['a'])) {
                    $corrupt_a_array = $result[$i]['a'];
                    $fixed_arrays = array_merge($fixed_arrays, $corrupt_a_array);
                }
            }
            $result['data'] = $fixed_arrays;  // This $result['data'] should show the expected result.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you are asking to do with Set::combine (or Hash::combine in later versions of CakePHP). It just doesn't work that way.  However, you can simplify what you are currently doing with the following:

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $data){
    $yourArray[$key] = $data['MyData'] + $data['c'] + $data['a'];
}
```

This will output what you are looking for.

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [MyData] => Array (
      [id] => 79
      [my_birth_day] => 1990-06-20
      [my_address] => 400
      [my_age] => 26
      [my_name] => Joy
      [my_id] => 1
      [created] => 2017-06-19 15:39:44
      [my_test] => math
      [my_date] => 2017-08-13
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = Set::combine('', '{n}.MyData', '{n}.c', '{n}.a');
```

i hope this useful for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is marked as a correct answer.  I am pretty certain that Set::combine (or Hash::combine in newer versions of CakePHP) can not be used to do what the original question is asking.  You can't provide multiple child arrays as the valuePath (parameter 3) in the function.  Also, strictly following the answer provided, parameter 1 is expecting an array, '{n}.MyData' as parameter 2 would produce an error since the keyPath can't resolve to an array, and '{n}.a' would also produce an error since the groupPath also can't resolve to an array.

Comment: I agreed. but @tony asked answer for cakephp version 2. i replied accordingly. thanks.